How to use Oracle Autonomous DB wallet files for AWS Glue Connection
I'm currently trying to create an AWS Glue connection (jdbc type) to connect to an Oracle Autonomous database. I have provided an username and password, and the connection URL provided is as follows: jdbc:oracle:oci8:@//IP_ADDRESS:1522/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.ccc.oraclecloud.com. The driver we are using is ojdbc10.jar from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-drivers-archive.html
However, when trying to use the connection we get an error:
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12506, TNS:listener rejected connection based on service ACL filtering
Which, the database administrator has confirmed that our IP address has been whitelisted.
We are meant to use a provided wallet, and we currently have the following files: truststore.jks, tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora, ojdbc.properties, ewallet.pem and ewallet.p12, cwallet.sso and keystore.jks. I'm not sure how to provide/specify these files to be used, while creating the glue connection, to use the wallet files.
Any recommendations on how to proceed with this?
thanks
